# Resort python list for boxplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create boxplots of values at certain ranges.
Data comes from a textfile, which looks like that:

```
range;int
3;200
3;200
3;200
3;200
3;200
3;200
3;100
3;200
3;200
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;300
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;400
5;300
5;400
```

First row is range, second rows are the values. 
As you notice, the first row contains duplicates.
Read in :

```
 data = np.genfromtxt('out.txt', delimiter=';', names=True, dtype= int)
```

If i try to use this data in

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(data['range'], patch_artist=True)
plt.show()
```

It only make one boxplot for all 'int'. How to resort the data or adjust the skript in order to achieve a boxplot for each unique range?

Answer (score 1):

To re-sort the data, you can use Python's built-in sorted function:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('out.txt', delimiter=';', names=True, dtype=int)
data_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda value: (value[0], value[1]))
```

EDIT after comment from dh81 above:

If you are looking for the sorted data within each range, you could find the distinct range values and create a dictionary with the sorted arrays. Here is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

# Get and sort the data
data = np.genfromtxt('out.txt', delimiter=';', names=True, dtype=int)
data_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda value: (value[0], value[1]))

# Prepare dictionary to hold different arrays
data_dict = {}

# Find the different ranges needed
range_keys = set([i[0] for i in data])

# Populate each range with the values
for range_key in range_keys:
    range_values = []
    for data_point in data_sorted:
        if data_point[0] == range_key:
            range_values.append(data_point)
    data_dict.update({range_key: range_values})

print("Got the dictionary of arrays: {}".format(data_dict))
```

Comment: That does not help. The data needs to be resortet in different arrays for each specific range.

Comment: Check out my edit just above. I think this is what you are looking for.